# How to store data in a hidden field and the pass it between pages in razor pages

Tags: c#, razor-pages

So I am trying to select a value from dropdown list and passing it as query string in a another view this works fine on get but for post I want to store it in a hidden field

```
<div style="margin: 30px">
     <label asp-for="DropDown" class="control-label">DropDownList</label>
     <select asp-items="Model.dropdown" 
             asp-for="targetvalue" 
             value ="targetvalue" 
             type="hidden" class="form-control">
     </select>
```

Not sure if this is correct how do I retrieve the hidden field to use it in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you should bind the value to a page model field, then just generate a hidden input in your form;

```cs
<input type="hidden" asp-for="targetvalue" />
```

Comment: to bind just use the attribute [BindProperty] ?

Comment: Right, as with any other form value.

Comment: And how do I use this hidden field value between other views ?

Comment: When the web browser does the POST it gets the selected value (not text) from the drop-down list, So in your case you can retrieve the selected value from server side. But looks like you want to retrieve  the selected text , and for that purpose you need to use a hidden field with JavaScript to set selected text. But the recommenced approach is to use Id and query your database / some sort of server side data pool for security reasons. But if you really need it you can add another property to your model and add a hidden filed to match with new property name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of below methods, But the recommended way is "Model Binding".

1. You can access the value by passing the key as an indexer to the Request.Form collection, like below:

   ```
   var number = Request.Form["targetvalue"];
   ```
2. Add a suitable property to the PageModel and to allow model binding to apply the posted value to the property: like below:

   ```
      public IndexModel : PageModel
      {
         [BindProperty]
         public int targetvalue { get; set; }
         public void OnPost()
         {
              // posted value is assigned to the targetvalue property automatically
         }
      }
   ```

For this example the Drop-down list can be rendered in different ways, But once it rendered into HTML it would look like below:

```
<select name="targetvalue">
    <option value="">Select a number</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```